# QtService does not pass the start parameters from Service Manager window

Tags: qt

How to get the Start parameters that are passed from the Windows Service Manager dialog. I was hoping I would get them as command line args passed to the main function.

[image]

If I pass the arguments to binPath when creating the service then I get the arguments passed into main function.

```
sc create "Myservice" binPath= "Path_to_exe\Myservice.exe -port 18082"
```

But this way we need to uninstall and install the service everytime to change any arguments.
Is there any way to get the start parameters in Qt?

If I create the service using .NET, I can use the following function to get these Start parameters.

```
 System::Environment::GetCommandLineArgs();
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question is old, but how it keeps unanswered and the problem persist until nowadays, I believe that is appropriate give a possible answer.

You will be able to get the start parameters of a Qt Service by reimplementing `void QtServiceBase::createApplication ( int & argc, char ** argv )`

According to the [docs](http://doc.qt.digia.com/solutions/4/qtservice/qtservicebase.html#createApplication):

```
This function is only called when no service specific arguments were passed to the service constructor, and is called by exec() before it calls the executeApplication() and start() functions.
```

So when your service call the start function the args will be available, because the `createApplication` is called before the `start` function.

Here a example:

```
#include <QtCore>
#include "qtservice.h"

class Service : public QtService<QCoreApplication>
{
public:
    explicit Service(int argc, char *argv[], const QString &name) : QtService<QCoreApplication>(argc, argv, name)
    {
        setServiceDescription("Service");
        setServiceFlags(QtServiceBase::CanBeSuspended);
        setStartupType(QtServiceController::ManualStartup);
    }

protected:
    void start()
    {
        // use args;
    }

    void stop()
    {
    }

    void pause()
    {
    }

    void resume()
    {
    }

    void processCommand(int code)
    {
    }

    void createApplication(int &argc, char **argv)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
            args.append(QString(argv[i]));

        QtService::createApplication(argc, argv);
    }
private:
    QStringList args;
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Service s(argc, argv, "Service");
    return s.exec();
}
```